# How can I know which files were modified by a certain author?

Tags: git

I want to have a list of the files that where modified by a certain author. How can I do this with git?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command:

`git log --no-merges --stat --author="User" --name-only --pretty=format:"" | sort -u`

Answer (score 0):

Go through the `git log` output, and look for the author fields:

```
git log --author 'marcus'
```

will give you all git log entries of an author which contains `marcus`; note that regular expressions can be used here.

```
git log --author marcus -p --name-only --pretty=''
```

will really only give you the file names, but unsorted and also with duplicates

```
git log --author marcus -p --name-only --pretty=''|sort|uniq
```

will solve that.

Generally, I'd say

```
git log --author marcus -p
```

is most useful.